# how to set color around slider image using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap design ,I set some images in my slider design
but around slider images i found blank("Gray Color") but I want set
diffrent color but it is not working. I tried this way.
[image]

I want to add color to the yellow marked area .
mainPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your Online Store</title>
    <!-- Add Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Add your custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/mainPage.css}" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    //code of navbar
</nav>

<!-- Hero Section -->
<header class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="container slider-container">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" th:src="@{/images/pairShoe.jpg}" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" th:src="@{/images/shoestext.jpg}" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" th:src="@{/images/printTshirt.jpg}" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" th:src="@{/images/jeenspieces.jpg}" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<!-- rest code -->

</body>
</html>
```

mainPage.css

```
.slider-container {
    background-color: #005CAF;
}
```

but this code not working ,not set any background color in yellow
marked area.

Answer (score 0):

The yellow marked area is actually padding around your header element. To color that area, I targeted the "jumbotron" class in mainPage.css, instead of the "slider-container" div element.

```
.jumbotron {
    background-color: #005CAF;
}
```

You could also add vertical padding to the div, if you're determined to select it.

```
.slider-container {
    background-color: #005CAF;
    padding: 50px 0px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
.jumbotron {
  background-color: green !important;
 }
.slider-container {
  background-color: #005CAF;
}
```

You have to do something like this, you have to give **background-color** to your parent header as you want. Hope so your code will execute properly